# So, "I feel amazing" is not grammatically wrong but it is not popular right?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

**amazing**: very surprising, especially in a way that makes you feel pleasure or admiration; Ex: *That's amazing, isn't it?* ([Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/amazing?q=amazing))

**amazed**: very surprised; EX: *I was amazed at her knowledge of French literature.* [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/amazed)

So, I think we should say "*I feel amazed*". However, searching for "*I feel amazing*" returns 400K results, while "*I feel amazed*" returns only 20K results.

But in NGram, "*I feel amazed*" is more prevalent than "*I feel amazing*" [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+feel+amazing%2C+I+feel+amazed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20amazing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20amazed%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: They mean different things. "I feel fantastic"  vs "I feel surprised"

Answer (score 1):

*[Amazing](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/amazing)* has another meaning

> MAINLY SPOKEN very pleasant or enjoyable
>   *We had an amazing time in Thailand.*
>   *What an amazing meal!*

*Macmillan*

Comment: But I still feel "I feel amazing" term is weird

Comment: Check out these hits on [ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i%20feel%20amazing%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2008,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: So Oxford dictionary has not updated  the second meaning of "**amazing**"?

Comment: No, but [*Cambridge*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amazing?a=british) has.

Comment: based on Ngram, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+feel+amazing%2C+I+feel+amazed&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20amazing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20feel%20amazed%3B%2Cc0, I think "**I feel amazing**" was only used recently since 1970. I think it was a wrong way of using "**amazing**" at that time but gradually somehow people adopted it & give an extra meaning for it

Comment: Language shifts. Amazing!

Comment: @bib which sense of amazing is that?

Comment: @phoog I'm amazed that it's not obvious! And this banter is amazing as well.

Comment: It's very common for words expressing quality or pleasurability to change meaning or lose force: fantastic, awesome, stunning, smashing, delightful, and many more